# How to escape special characters in long sed string

Tags: sed, special-characters

I have this string that I want to include at line 115 of a file, using sed.
However, it always complains on some unknown command. I have followed other solutions in other questions, but haven't managed to solve it.

```
sed '115"<"img src="\.\/index_files\/Logo\.png" width="200" height="160" align="right" border="0">"' index.html > test.html
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `"` is not a `sed` command. As it says in the error message, though not very clearly.

The address `115` has to be followed by a `sed` command, probably `i`

- Then get rid of some of the `"`s. The ones around the `<` and after the `>`
- Then don't escape the `/`s, they don't need escaping.
- Then don't escape anything as `i` command just takes text.

This left we with: `sed '115 i <img src="./index_files/Logo.png" width="200" height="160" align="right" border="0">'`

Answer (score 2):

User richard describes very well what's wrong with your `sed` command, and also gives the correct editing script to perform the action you're attempting.

I'm giving an alternative approach which will work in a number of different cases:

The `sed` command `r` will insert the contents of a file at the current position in the data stream.

Your `sed` command line *could* be written

```
$ sed '115r /dev/stdin' index.html <data.in
```

which would have the same effect as `sed '115r data.in' index.html`... if the data that you wanted to insert after line 115 was stored in the file `data.in`.

`/dev/stdin` is a special file that contains whatever is sent through the standard input.

You could also do (with shells supporting "here-strings"):

```
$ sed '115r /dev/stdin' index.html <<<"my string of stuff"
```

or

```
$ sed '115r /dev/stdin' index.html <<<"$myvariableofwonder"
```

This also works as expected with piping from other commands, obviously:

```
$ sed -n '1,10p' myfile | sed '115r /dev/stdin' index.html
```

This will transplant lines 1 to 10 of `myfile` into `index.html` at line 115.

Comment: I like this. However be aware that some systems, Microsoft's Windows is an example do not have `/dev/stdin`. (for some tools such as gnu awk, it will interpret the `/dev/stdin` it self so will work on these legacy systems).

Comment: @richard Good point. Does work in Microsoft's new Linux environment, and in Cygwin, but not in MinGW (no `/dev`).

Comment: Oh good they got `/dev/stdin` working in gnu/cygwin now. It did not work when I used it about 10 years ago.

Comment: What about MacOS X, BSD and other Unixes do they have `/dev/stdin`?

Comment: @richard Yes, because POSIX.

Comment: @richard It's _actually_ no real requirement but "The system may provide non-standard extensions. These are features not required by POSIX.1-2008 and may include, but are not limited to: [...] Additional character special files with special properties (for example, `/dev/stdin`, `/dev/stdout`, and `/dev/stderr`)".   I know of no Unix without them.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Very helpful indeed! However, I marked the other as accepted, since it was solving exactly the question as you said.