# Unix systems without /dev/stdin, /dev/stdout, and /dev/stderr?

Tags: posix, stdout, stdin, stderr

[An answer I gave to a question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/338654/116858), and the comments to it, had me read the [POSIX Conformance section of the Base Definitions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap02.html) to figure out whether `/dev/stdin`, `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr` were actually needed for conformance to the POSIX standard.

It turns out they are not:

> The system may provide non-standard extensions. These are features not required by POSIX.1-2008 and may include, but are not limited to: [...] Additional character special files with special properties (for example, `/dev/stdin`, `/dev/stdout`, and `/dev/stderr`)

As far as I can find, this is the *only* mentioning of these files in the standard.

I have access to only one "system" (environment, really) which does not implement them, and that's MinGW on Windows (no `/dev` at all as far as I can see).  As far as I know, all the free Unices have them, and so does Cygwin, Windows' new Linux environment and Darwin/macOS.

I'm not well versed with the commercial Unices though.

Is there a POSIX system, Unix, or a Unix-like environment of some description, alive today, that does not implement `/dev/stdin`, `/dev/stdout`, and `/dev/stderr` as files in the filesystem?

Comment: Related: [portability of file descriptor links](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123602/portability-of-file-descriptor-links)

Comment: Also related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36403/portability-of-dev-stdout - this provides a list of platforms where it allegedly does not work in csh (csh being mainly relevant as an example of a shell other than bash, which may implement special handling for these names).

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks. Yes, it's somewhat related, but I'm interested in the availability of `/dev/std{in,out,err}` files rather than the availability of the `/dev/fd` and `/proc` hierarchies.

Comment: @Random832 This is interesting, but it's a shame that [Ola's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278368/116858) doesn't include what he means by "works". As some utilities and shells apparently _simulate_ these files, it would be nice to know what the test was...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a POSIX system, Unix, or a Unix-like environment of some description, alive today, that does not implement /dev/stdin, /dev/stdout, and /dev/stderr as files in the filesystem?

Yes, at least per my example system below.

I'm not an expert in this system by any means; however, AIX 6.1, which wikipedia claims is:

> one of five commercial operating systems that have versions certified to The Open Group's UNIX 03 standard 
>   (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX)

does not appear to implement those file descriptors in the installation I have access to.  As you can see, if using bash, it will behave as if they did exist for the purposes of redirection:

```
$ uname -s
AIX
$ echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/ksh
$ ls -al /dev/stdin
ls: 0653-341 The file /dev/stdin does not exist.
$ ls -al /dev/stdout
ls: 0653-341 The file /dev/stdout does not exist.
$ ls -al /dev/stderr
ls: 0653-341 The file /dev/stderr does not exist.
$ echo foo >/dev/stderr
The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.
ksh: /dev/stderr: 0403-005 Cannot create the specified file.
$ bash
bash-4.2$ ls /dev/stderr
ls: 0653-341 The file /dev/stderr does not exist.
bash-4.2$ echo foo >/dev/stderr
foo
```

As other commenters have mentioned, the following questions provide some interesting information as well:

- [Portability of "> /dev/stdout"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36403/portability-of-dev-stdout)
- [Portability of file descriptor links](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123602/portability-of-file-descriptor-links)

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting well after the initial posts but thought I'd add this comment for future viewers.

I get the same results writing to /dev/stdout as above on an AIX 6.1 system, but on an AIX 7.1 system it works as expected, so it looks support for /dev/stdout was added.

AIX 6.1 (ksh93)

```
echo "Hello" > /dev/stdout                                            
ksh93: /dev/stdout: cannot create.
[The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.].
```

AIX 7.1 (ksh93)

```
echo "Hello" > /dev/stdout
Hello
```

Comment: What about /dev/stdin?

Comment: I don't know about aix, but that test is lousy: some shells implement /dev/stdout as a fake file hack if the OS doesn't support it. You should demonstrate that by passing the path to an external program:  `cat /dev/stdin`.