# How to insert command output directly into a file before a pattern?

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, sed

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32908/how-to-insert-the-content-of-a-file-into-another-file-before-a-pattern-marker#32912) and its answers show the content of an existing file ("processedFile") can be inserted into another existing file ("receivingFile") before one of its *pattern*s inside, such that:

```
sed -i -e '/pattern/r processedFile' receivingFile
```

At times, such content might result from a *previous command-unit*, and is not yet written.

At that point, is it possible to insert the outcome of the command-unit into receivingFile without creating/writing processedFile?

Example:

Say, we preprocessed `someFile` as follows (reading its content starting from the 4th line to the end of file):

```
awk 'NR>3' someFile
```

Now, without writing this to a new file, we want to directly insert it into receivingFile before a *pattern* such that:

```
awk 'NR>3' someFile | <insertion commands>
```

PS: Preferably by using `awk` or `sed`.

---

Based on the request from @RomanPerekhrest,

*someFile*:

```
# random output
# random
11
0 0 0 23.259058 2.1756592 -1.2097659 -0.074128056 0.34343502 -0.017659865
0 0 0.05 51.091269 4.8520157 -0.0011590485 0.00096592555 0.0059719715 -0.050598505
```

Preprocessing:

`awk 'NR>3' someFile` :

```
0 0 0 23.259058 2.1756592 -1.2097659 -0.074128056 0.34343502 -0.017659865
0 0 0.05 51.091269 4.8520157 -0.0011590485 0.00096592555 0.0059719715 -0.050598505
```

*receivingFile* :

```
stackExchange is the best.
pattern
Unix stackExchange is the best of the bests.
```

Comment: from what I see, I’d say use `cat someFile | awk 'NR>3' | <insertion commands>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't tell if it's portable accross all *NIX, depending on implementation. It's working on my Linux Debian.

TL;DR: use `/dev/stdin` as included file, which is sed's input and will get the output of the command before the pipe, like

```
awk 'NR>3' someFile | sed -i -e '/pattern/r /dev/stdin' receivingFile
```

Example: destination file contents called `receivingFile`:

```
stackExchange is the best.
pattern
Unix stackExchange is the best of the bests.
```

Input sample called `someFile`:

```
# random output
# random
11
0 0 0 23.259058 2.1756592 -1.2097659 -0.074128056 0.34343502 -0.017659865
0 0 0.05 51.091269 4.8520157 -0.0011590485 0.00096592555 0.0059719715 -0.050598505
```

To insert after the pattern:

```
awk 'NR>3' someFile | sed -e '/pattern/r /dev/stdin' receivingFile
```

To insert before the pattern, reusing the [answer linked by OP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32908/how-to-insert-the-content-of-a-file-into-another-file-before-a-pattern-marker#32912) and dump to output:

```
awk 'NR>3' someFile | sed -n -e '/pattern/r /dev/stdin' -e 1x -e '2,${x;p}' -e '${x;p}' receivingFile
```

To do what was asked and also replace the file:

```
awk 'NR>3' someFile | sed -i -n -e '/pattern/r /dev/stdin' -e 1x -e '2,${x;p}' -e '${x;p}' receivingFile
```

New content of receivingFile:

```
stackExchange is the best.
0 0 0 23.259058 2.1756592 -1.2097659 -0.074128056 0.34343502 -0.017659865
0 0 0.05 51.091269 4.8520157 -0.0011590485 0.00096592555 0.0059719715 -0.050598505
pattern
Unix stackExchange is the best of the bests.
```

**UPDATE**: as noted by @don_crissti, this doesn't work if *pattern* is the last line. Here's an other command, adapted from [his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32908/how-to-insert-the-content-of-a-file-into-another-file-before-a-pattern-marker/193498#193498) to the same linked question! Some other command is needed to accomodate with the temporary addition (and suppression by sed) of the extra blank line. These two would work:

```
awk 'NR>3' someFile | sed -e '/pattern/{r/dev/stdin' -e 'N;:l;$!n;$!bl};${/^$/!{s/\n$//};//d}' receivingFile <(printf '\n') > receivingFile.new
mv receivingFile.new receivingFile
```

or just (not needing bash and leaving `sed -i` to handle the final file):

```
awk 'NR>3' someFile | { echo '' >> receivingFile; sed -i -e '/pattern/{r/dev/stdin' -e 'N;:l;$!n;$!bl};${/^$/!{s/\n$//};//d}' receivingFile ; }
```

Look at the [linked answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32908/how-to-insert-the-content-of-a-file-into-another-file-before-a-pattern-marker/193498#193498) for the line-splitted sed code.

Comment: Related to  the question of portability: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338667/unix-systems-without-dev-stdin-dev-stdout-and-dev-stderr

Comment: If you read all the answers there (instead of just copying _jfg956_'s solution which partially works) you'll learn that the stuff you used in your answer here _only works if `pattern` is **not** on the last line_. If it's on the last line the stuff from `/dev/stdin` will be inserted after `pattern` (not before it, as required here).

Answer (score 3):

Just use `ex`, the POSIX-specified scriptable form of `vi` (which is also POSIX-specified).

```
printf '%s\n' '/pattern/-r !awk "NR>3" somefile' x | ex receivingFile
```

Or more generally:

```
printf '%s\n' '/pattern/-r !somecommand' x | ex somefile
```

Comment: `ed` is better than `ex` for this.  `/bin/ed` is an ~ 50KB binary.  `/usr/bin/ex` is a symlink or hardlink to `vi` - if that `vi` is `vim`, then it'll be at least a 1MB binary (for `vim.tiny` on debian. or more depending on what's compiled into vim - e.g. 2.5MB for `vim.basic`, 3.1MB for `vim.gtk3`).  Even `nvi` is about 470KB.

Comment: @cas, "ed is better than ex for this" — that really depends on context.  If the context is an embedded system or one where performance is *absolutely critical*, that may be true.  It's not an absolute truth.  You could also say that handling it in assembly is "better" because if it's well written you can get an even smaller binary—which we would both agree is nonsense.  `ex` is far more flexible than `ed` and also has the advantage that it's *already* the editor of choice for most sysadmins (who use `vi`)—they just don't know it exists yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "far more flexible"?  `ex` is a clone of `ed` (actually, of `em` which was a clone of `ed` for use on new-fangled video terminals), - is there any scriptable editing operation that `ex` can do that `ed` can not?   BTW, it **is** an absolute truth that executing a 50KB binary is always better than executing a 1MB binary that does the exact same thing.

Comment: @cas, you can compare [the specs for `ed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html) and [the specs for `ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) and find for yourself the differences in functionality.  (Registers come to mind.)  But the crucial distinction is that `ex` is already built in to the editor of choice used by *most* sysadmins.  `ed` is not.  Knowledge of `ex` is directly and immediately usable in everyday editing tasks, without leaving your `vi` session.  (NB: If you reply to this pugnaciously do not expect another response.)

Comment: The "specs" for `ed` and `ex` are trivially different.  The edit operations in `ex` are the same as those in `ed`.  Your alleged advantage that "ex is already built in to the editor of choice used by most sysadmins" is no advantage at all because `ex` commands are identical to `ed`.     The actual difference is the difference between running a 50KB binary and a 500K or 1M or 2.5MB symlink to vi/vim.  BTW, it is you that has been replying pugnaciously - you seem to have taken offence at my initial comment and responded in an obnoxiously defensive manner as if I had made some personal criticism.

Comment: "smaller is better" is also the reason why, for example, even though `perl` can trivially emulate `sed` with its `-n` or `-p` options, it is better to use `sed` rather than `perl` unless you're doing something that requires `perl`'s features.  The extra startup overhead of the much larger `perl` interpreter is worth avoiding if it's not needed.

Comment: @don_crissti, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

With sed (GNU sed) 4.4

```
sed -i '/pattern/{h;s/.*/awk "NR>3" somefile/e;p;x}' receivingFile
```